# Saving data from Firebase into a list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently developing an Android app that deals with storing book translations. I'm using Firebase to hold all the data online, and I have no trouble pulling data from it and storing them as Book objects. I have a master list of books in the main class that stores all the books from the Firebase database, however the list doesn't seem to update properly.

```
public static List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot bookSnapshhot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Book book = bookSnapshhot.getValue(Book.class);
                books.add(book);
                System.out.println(book.getAuthor() + " - " + book.getTitle());
                for (Chapter chapter : book.getChapters()) {
                    System.out.println(chapter.getTitle());
                }
                for (Genre genre : book.getGenres()) {
                    System.out.println(genre.getGenre());
                }
                System.out.println(books.size());
            }
        }
        @Override public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) { }
    });
    System.out.println(books.size());
}
```

In that body, the size of books is correct (right now it is only 1). However if I call the same print statement outside of that code body (the last line), it gives me 0. I don't know why, because it successfully adds it inside the onDataChange() method but it seems to not apply the changes on the outside.

Comment: Shadab's answer explains it: you cannot return something now that hasn't loaded yet. You might also want to read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener. It uses a few more words to explain it (albeit in a different context: writing data).

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is about the asyncronously of the ValueEventListener.

The onDataChange is called asynconously.

You have to use the books after the onDataChange is called.

Answer (score 2):

The `addValueEventListener()` will fetch the data from `Firebase` asynchronously.
What your code depicts is that you are adding `ValueEventListener` and then printing `System.out.println(books.size());`. This means your logs gets displayed  after you add `ValueEventListener`(which doesn't means your listener gets invoked). At this point your listener is not invoked yet and so isn't  `onDataChange()`. Thus you won't ever get updated count outside the listener scope.

Comment: Interesting. How can I figure out when onDataChange() gets invoked then?

Comment: `onDataChange()` will get invoked everytime the child nodes under `myFirebaseRef` gets changed.